# Is there any method to get cart details inside a plugin feature in Magento 2

Tags: plugins, magento2, cart

How can I get cart products in a custom module plugin in magento 2 on before-save shipping info hear already i'm taking the customer address its working fine like this i need to get the cart products also

> /app/code/Sem/Shipment/Plugin/Checkout/Model/ShippingInformationManagement.php

```
class ShippingInformationManagement
{

    protected $_messageManager;
    protected $jsonResultFactory;
    protected $_cart;    

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $jsonResultFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cartModel
    ) {
        $this->_messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->jsonResultFactory = $jsonResultFactory;
         $this->_cart = $cartModel;
    }

    public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\ShippingInformationManagement $subject,
        $cartId,
        \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation

    )
    {

    $items = $this->_cart->getAllVisibleItems();
    $result = [];
    if (count($items) > 0){
        foreach ($items as $item)
            $resulta = $item->getName();
    }
    $address = $addressInformation->getShippingAddress();
    $postcode = $address->getData('postcode');
    $objectManager =   \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $result = $this->jsonResultFactory->create();
    throw new StateException(__($resulta));             
}
}
```

Heare i am getting

> $items = $this->_cart->getAllVisibleItems(); as empty value but the product is in cart

Answer (score 0):

We assume you need to product name only.

In your custom module PHP function:

```
protected $_quote;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory
    /*Other DIs if you have*/
)
{
    $this->_quote= $quoteFactory;
    /*Other DIs  if you have*/
}

public function beforeSaveAddressInformation(
    \Magento\Checkout\Api\ShippingInformationManagementInterface $subject,
    $cartId,
    \Magento\Checkout\Api\Data\ShippingInformationInterface $addressInformation
){
    //Inside 
    $cart = $this->_quote->create()->get($cartId);
    $items = $cart->getAllVisibleItems();
    $result = [];
    if (count($items) > 0){
        foreach ($items as $item)
            $result[] = $item->getName();
            //If you need other fields, please let me know.
            //$result[] = $item->getData();
    }
    return $result;
}
```